# Prós e contras do paradigma funcional e do Haskell

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

Eu vi que, claramente, o paradgima de Programação Funcional não é nada famoso no mundo da programação em geral. Entretanto, conversando com um poucos fãs de linguagens como Lisp, Ocaml, F#, Haskell, etc. Vi argumentos que quase chegaram a me convencer a aprender a linguagem puramente funcional que parece ser a mais influente e popular do momento: Haskell.

Então, a pergunta é fundamentalmente esta: Quais os prós e contras da programação funcional? Quais os prós e contras de Haskell? Por que eu deveria aprender Haskell?

Só pra deixar uma pista, um dos argumentos que eu mais escutei dos fãs do paradigma funcional foi:
"Paralelismo e threading em programação funcional é quase que trivial de tão simples, enquanto em outras linguagens isso é difícil, árduo e devido a má implementação só trás problemas".

Comment: Depois da sua pergunta, surgiu essa, seria legal conciliar as idéias, ou deixar essa mais focada no haskell em si: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13372/programacao-funcional-e-programacao-orientada-a-objetos-o-que-sao-e-quais-suas (não é duplicata, só linkei para fazer o cross-linking para os interessados)

Comment: @Bacco Na minha opinião, é melhor deixar como perguntas separadas. Não entendo suficientemente de Haskell pra responder, mas sei que ele é bastante diferente das linguagens funcionais mais "populares" (Lisp, F#) pelo seu sistema de tipos bastante rígido (além do fato de ser "puramente" funcional - ao contrário de Lisp, por exemplo, que inclui características não funcionais). Ou seja, não se trata apenas de discutir **características funcionais** - que podem se aplicar mesmo a linguagens imperativas, como Python e Ruby - mas sim de uma linguagem que não foge desse paradigma nem um milímetro.

Comment: Ser "puro" e ser "funcional" são conceitos separados, ainda que relacionados. Isso significa, por exemplo, que Scheme (um tipo de Lisp) não é "menos" funcional que Haskell, apesar de só a última ser considerada "pura". Ver http://stackoverflow.com/a/4382400/158074. Mas, de fato, Common Lisp já não é considerada uma linguagem funcional, justamente por admitir o estilo imperativo.

Answer (score 19):

Pra falar a verdade, eu acho que o termo "programação funcional" não é muito preciso, e eu preferiria separar os Lisps das linguagens tipadas no estilo ML (Haskell, Ocaml, F#, etc). Dito isso, para responder a pergunta "porque aprender Haskell", acho melhor dividir em duas partes.

1. **Programação Funcional em geral**

   Uma coisa que todas as linguagens funcionais tem em comum é a forma como as funções são valores de primeira categoria: Você pode definir funções dentro de outras funções (acessando as variáveis da função de fora), definir funções que recebem outras funções como parâmetro ou que retornam funções... Isso é bastante flexível e permite escrever muitas coisas de forma sucinta.

   Hoje em dia, esse ponto da programação funcional não é mais uma distinção tão importante, já que muitas linguagens "imperativas" tem funções de primeira classe e até linguagens notáveis pela falta de funções anônimas, como Java e C++ estão finalmente as incluindo. E já que falamos em programação imperativa, pra falar a verdade, a programação funcional nem precisa ser tão diferente assim - dá pra escrever programas com uma cara bastante imperativa se usarmos recursão de cauda (algo equivalente a gotos computados).
2. **Linguagens da família ML (Haskell, Ocaml, etc)**

   O fator mais único de Haskell e suas linguagens primas (Ocaml, F#, etc) certamente é o sistema de tipos, extremamente poderoso e flexível, mas ainda relativamente fácil de usar. Eu diria que vale a pena aprender uma linguagem dessas só por isso. Alguns dos pontos mais importantes:

   - O sistema de tipos é completamente estático. Muitas erros que são detectados em tempo de execução em outras linguagens são detectados em tempo de compilação em Haskell.
   - Variáveis sempre estarão inicializadas (não é possível acessar uma variável não inicializada).
   - Polimorfismo paramétrico / generics. Permite expressar tipos precisos, sem ter que fazer upcasting e downcasting com um supertipo Object.
   - Uniões tageadas e "pattern matching". É possível descrever tipos com mais de um caso (por exemplo, "valor inteiro ou null") e é fácil escrever programas que tratam todos esses casos (o pattern matching é uma mistura de switch com desestruturação). Isso tudo evita exceções como NullPointerExceptions, já que o tipo de uma variável nulável não é o mesmo tipo de uma variável não nulável.
   - A inferência de tipos é poderosa e se você quiser você pode escrever qualquer programa sem usar nenhuma anotação de tipo, o que evita chatices como `MyClass myClass = new MyClass`. Dito isso, ainda é uma boa ideia botar umas anotações de tipo aqui e ali para deixar as mensagens de erro mais compreensíveis.
3. **Haskell, específicamente**

   - Haskell é uma das linguagens funcionais com a comunidade mais ativa. Vai ser mais fácil encontrar documentação, [bibliotecas](http://hackage.haskell.org/) e [livros introdutórios](http://learnyouahaskell.com) para Haskell. Em particular, Haskell tem algumas bibliotecas realmente legais, que não são comuns em outras linguagens:

     - [Quickcheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck). Gera entradas aleatórias para seus casos de teste de forma automática, baseada nos tipos das funções.
     - [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). Faz buscas na biblioteca padrão de Haskell baseado nos tipos. Uma forma extremamente rápida e eficaz de procurar funções, se você souber o que você quer que eles recebam e retornem mas não souber o nome deles.
     - [Parser Combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator). Uma forma flexível de escrever seus próprios parsers mas que seria difícil e feio de implementar em linguagens convencionais.
     - Haskell usa avaliação preguiçosa, o que facilita definir o seus próprios combinadores e estruturas de controle de fluxo. Para um exemplo um pouco forçado, podemos definir

       meuIfThenElse cond ifTrue ifFalse = 
             if cond then ifTrue else ifFalse

     Em Haskell, essa função se comporta exatamente como um if. Já em uma linguagem com avaliação estrita, essa função não funcionaria tão bem, já que os dois parâmetros ifTrue e ifFalse seriam sempre avaliados, ao invés de um só ser. Seria preciso explicitamente embrulhá-los em umas funções extras:

     ```
       function meuIfThenElse(cond, onTrue, onFalse){
           if(cond){ onTrue() } else { onFalse() }
       }
     ```
   - Devido à avaliação preguiçosa, Haskell acaba tendo que separar código funcional sem efeitos colaterais do código com efeitos colaterais (que precisam ser executados em uma ordem precisa). Muita gente acha isso confuso no início (ter que usar monadas para imprimir e ler valores) mas depois que você aprende como funciona é bem útil ter o sistema de tipos marcando quais partes do programa podem ter efeitos colaterais e quais são puras. Se uma função for pura você pode chamar ela sem ter de se preocupar com quando ela roda ou com se ela vai alterar alguma variável de instância de um objeto seu.

Comment: Essa resposta me parece bem completa, excetuando um problema: Haskell definitivamente **não** faz parte da família ML! ML com certeza teve influência sobre Haskell (e também sobre Nemerle e Scala, por exemplo), mas dizer que fazem parte da mesma família é excessivo. Ver http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29 (em Inglês).

Comment: @rsenna: Juro que já vi gente usando essa terminologia (afinal, o sistema de tipos e sintaxe são bem parecidos) mas editei a resposta pra ficar mais claro, por via das dúvidas.

Comment: Você mesmo identifica algumas das principais diferenças: 1) as linguagens ML são, por definição, *impuras*, e o mesmo não acontece com o Haskell. 2) ML é *eager*, Haskell é *lazy*. Haskell teve *influência* de várias linguagens: ML, Miranda, Scheme, e até Python. Mas é uma linguagem suficientemente diferente para ser considerada de forma isolada. Se é necessário colocá-la em uma família, considere que ela é a "matriarca" de uma nova (a qual já pertencem algumas outras linguagens, como a [Frege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frege_%28programming_language%29) por exemplo) :).

Answer (score 12):

Já foram dadas boas respostas, mas ainda faltou responder a algumas dúvidas do OP, que tentarei tratar aqui

### Quais os prós e contras da programação funcional [em relação a paralelismo e threading]?

A questão aqui não é tanto o funcional vs. imperativo, e sim **mutabilidade** vs. **imutabilidade**.

Linguagens imperativas tendem a fazer um grande uso de estruturas e objetos *mutáveis*, com alteração de estado. Uma propriedade de um objeto, encapsulada por um par de métodos *get* e *set* é um exemplo disto.

Este estilo de programação costuma ser simples, em um ambiente *single-threaded*, mas ganha ordens de magnitude de complexidade quando se passa a considerar ambientes multi-processados. Pois, se mais de um processo pode ler e alterar uma variável, é necessário controlar os acessos *simultâneos* de leitura e de escrita à memória (através do uso de semáforos, por exemplo). E este controle, por ser muito complexo, é também muito sucetível a problemas, tais como *deadlocks*, baixa performance e outros erros de implementação.

Já as linguages funcionais tendem a utilizar somente estruturas e objetos *imutáveis*. Isso significa que objetos criados nunca mais são alterados (se uma informação precisa ser alterada, isso implica em criar um *novo* objeto, e não alterar o antigo).

Este estilo é muito mais custoso, do ponto de vista de consumo de memória, mas tem uma grande vantagem: todas as dificuldades associadas ao controle de leitura e escrita de memória deixam de existir (mas, claro, algumas *novas* dificuldades também surgem).

Vem daí também, em parte, a predileção das linguagens funcionais para com as *listas*, por serem estruturas que podem ser facilmente manipuláveis, sem abrir mão da imutabilidade (é possível "adicionar" um item a uma lista simplesmente ao criar um novo "head" que aponta para a lista antiga - ou seja, é criado um novo objeto lista, mas sem ser necessário copiar os itens da lista antiga para a nova, poupando processamento).

### Porque eu deveria aprender Haskell?

Essa é uma pergunta capciosa, pois eu **não acho** que você deva aprender Haskell (pelo menos não agora)!

Você (o OP) parece não ter muito conhecimento sobre linguagens funcionais. E Haskell é com toda a certeza uma das mais complexas e difíceis linguagens de programação para se aprender. Além da imutabilidade, você teria que aprender conceitos como lazyness, pureza, type-classes, mônadas, monóides, memória transacional... E, acredite, isso tudo é ainda mais estranho do que o fato dela ser funcional. :P (Na minha opinião, é mais ou menos como querer aprender Física Quântica, sem ter aprendido Física Clássica Newtoniana: é possível, só não é sensato).

Existem opções bem mais acessíveis:

- [Scheme](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme) é uma linguagem Lisp multi-paradigma, própria para estudantes, que faz uso forte dos conceitos funcionais, e é relativamente fácil de aprender (se você ignorar os parênteses).
- [Clojure](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) é mais um dialeto Lisp. Alguns afirmam que ele é ainda mais moderno e mais funcional que Scheme, com a vantagem de rodar na JVM. Pessoalmente ainda não tive a oportunidade de aprender Clojure mais a fundo, mas tudo indica que é uma das linguagens mais interessantes de se utilizar atualmente.
- [Scala](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) é uma linguagem que tenho experiência profissional, e que portanto posso falar melhor. À primeira vista parece muito com Java e Ruby, mas por "dentro" dá pra ver que se inspirou muito em Haskell. Não é totalmente funcional, e está longe de ser pura, mas costuma ser uma boa opção para aqueles que tem experiência em linguagens OOP como Java ou C#. Bibliotecas como a [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) (uma framework Web) permitem também ver, na prática, as vantagens (e desvantagens) do estilo funcional em áreas tipicamente dominadas pela orientação a objetos tradicional.
- [F#](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%E2%99%AF) é, assim como Scala, mais um exemplo de híbrido funcional x objetos. Mas F# "pega mais pesado" no lado funcional, por ser um superset de [Ocaml](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocaml). Também pode ajudar em se obter os "pré-requisitos" necessários pra se aprender Haskell (por exemplo, as [computation expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) de F# são mônadas, que por sua vez são muito importantes para se entender Haskell).

Fora essas, é possível utilizar o principal conceito funcional, *first-class functions*, em Ruby, Python e até mesmo em C# (3.0+) e Java (8.0+).

Comment: Não sei se concordo que Haskell é difícil de aprender. Para quem quer aprender Haskell e sabe ler inglês existe o [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) que é excelente. Em Português existe o "Haskell: Uma abordagem prática" e outros livros. O básico da linguagem é até bem simples, mas as partes avançadas da linguagem são realmente difíceis. Mas eu diria o mesmo em relação à C++. A maior diferença para mim é que Haskell não possui muito material de aprendizado, é mais difícil encontrar alguém para tirar suas dúvidas, etc.

Comment: @darque: não há muito o que argumentar aqui, já que estamos lidando apenas com opiniões. Mas acho que dá para objetivamente discordar de um ponto do que você falou: que apenas as "partes avançadas" de Haskell são realmente difíceis. Não, Haskell não pode ser acusada de ser desigual, ela é igualmente difícil em tudo. :) Nada é mais básico, talvez, que I/O, mas compare a forma de fazer I/O em C++ e em Haskell: é possível fazer I/O em C++ sem sequer saber o que é um template ou uma classe; mas não é possível fazer I/O em Haskell sem saber, pelo menos superficialmente, o que é uma mônada.

Comment: Cara, Java não tem first-class functions. Tudo o que há nele são interfaces funcionais: Interfaces com apenas um método, e é muito comum usar a interface como um utilitário para simular procedimentos sozinhos. Mas isso é uma solução verborrágica, dura de manter e inflexível: Um delegate no C# pode receber um método com qualquer número de parâmetros, uma interface funcional em Java sempre vai ter seu método interno com a mesma assinatura.

Comment: @Sid hã? Tem certeza que você está respondendo à pessoa certa?? :P Eu mal falei de Java na minha resposta!! (5 min depois) Ah entendi, é sobre o final. Você está desatualizado: [Java 8 possui first-class functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (mas a versão que eu indiquei estava errada; lambdas expressions foram introduzidas na versão 8, corrigido).

Comment: @rsenna eu estava respondendo a você mesmo, haha. É que no finalzinho você disse que o Java 8 tem first-class functions. Cara, tem certeza que ele tem? Essas lambdas expressions no Java 8 pra mim são meio que açucar sintático para classes anônimas. E mesmo que no Java 8 todo método que se encaixe numa interface dentro de java.util.function seja automaticamente referenciado como uma interface que implementa tal coisa, ainda não cabe dentro da definição de first-class function, não é?

Comment: @rsenna e como eu disse antes, em Javascript e C# você pode sempre reatribuir o objeto-função com funções de assinaturas diferentes. Em Java, as interfaces funcionais lhe prendem a sua assinatura original e trabalhar com esse tipo de coisa é estranho, apesar de resolver milhares de dores de cabeça e problemas que se tem em Java, como a necessidade de passar procedimentos a um método.

Comment: @sid Ok, entendi. Sobre lambdas em Java serem "açucar sintático": o que tu estás dizendo faz todo o sentido, mas não acho que isso sozinho "desmereça" a implementação Java. Um lambda em Java é uma first-class function, já que é um objeto; e é também uma closure, já que retém as "free-variables" referenciadas. Se no fim das contas isso gera um classe anônima, paciência. Aliás, [lambdas que referenciam free-variables são tratados de forma muito semelhante em C#](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained).

Comment: @sid (cont.) Já o que tu falaste sobre as interfaces funcionais é bem mais importante, na minha opinião. De fato, parece ser uma limitação bem grande, se comparada à forma como utilizamos lambdas em C#. *Me parece* que é possível minimizar este problema através de casts, mas não tenho certeza (eu trabalho com C# e com Scala, mas minha experiência com Java é bem mais limitada).

Comment: Então eu prefiro concluir que no final das contas, Java 8 não tem first-class functions reais. E uma das coisas que mais me enraivece no Java é justamente isso: A lerdeza que a linguagem tem para adquirir features presentes em outras linguagens. Entretanto é uma linguagem onde graças a presença quase zero de construções que demandam símbolos, é fácil escrever código legível nesta linguagem, apesar de mais trabalhoso.

Comment: E no final das contas, todas essas "frescurinhas" são mesmo necessárias? Digo: C permanece praticamente o mesmo por mais de 30 anos e até hoje faz o seu trabalho com maestria. E ele precisa continuar assim porque não é possível adicionar features ao C que criem um overhead considerável. E mesmo que C não tenha OOP, closures, lambdas, GC e etc, ainda é possível simular boa parte disso (principalmente OOP) e fazer as coisas como devem ser feitas.

Comment: @Sid Tuas citações estão corretas, mas tuas conclusões não fazem sempre sentido. Opiniões todos nós temos, vamos nos deter aos fatos, Ok? Java é diferente de C#, de Scala e de outras linguagens, e é bom que seja assim. É bom ter escolha, pois linguagens de programação são para seres-humanos. As máquinas só precisam de código binário. Todo o resto é "frescura", sejam first-class functions, classes ou passagem de parâmetros por stack. Mas é essa "frescura" que realmente importa, pelo menos para nós programadores.

Answer (score 7):

Não vou garantir que responderei sua pergunta com a excelência que você espera.

Primeiramente nunca é demais aprender algo novo. Pra falar a verdade é até saudável sair um pouco da zona de conforto. Sair dela sempre fará com que voltemos melhores do que quando saímos.

Uma coisa é aplicar esse tipo de paradigma no mercado que é totalmente dominado pelo OOP, Web e Mobile. Isso pode ser uma barreira, já que a maioria das empresas de TI trabalham com o feijão com arroz (CRUD, telinha que puxa dados daqui, imprime relatório de lá...).

Um ponto muito positivo da programação funcional é a possibilidade de se trabalhar com listas e realizar cálculos absurdos escrevendo pouquíssimo código. Fazemos muito escrevendo muito pouco, acho que isso é um dos pontos mais forte desse tipo de linguagem.

Por fim, estamos na era da integração. Não existem barreiras que te lhe impedirão de integrar o Haskell com outra linguagem de mercado. Hoje pra tudo existe uma jeito. :)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Por falar nisso, o que são listas em programação funcional? Tenho visto esse termo constantemente mas nunca o entendi por completo. Listas por acaso só uma forma de representar uma estrutura de dados nessas linguagens? Como os structs do C e os objetos de OOP?

Comment: @Sid, então cabe uma pergunta só para isso e não um contário, certo?

Comment: @Sid as listas do Haskell são basicamente listas ligadas, uma das estruturas de dados que são fáceis de traduzir do paradigma imperativo para o funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo [este tutorial de Haskell em português](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/introduction), que o autor chamou de "Aprender Haskell será um grande bem para você". Ensina Haskell de forma bem didática e fluente, leve, amigável. Vale a pena conferir.

**Edição:**

Acabo de descobrir que esse tutorial é a versão em português do [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), que já foi citado aqui [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13359/pr%C3%B3s-e-contras-do-paradigma-funcional-e-do-haskell#comment32286_14338).