# Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, programação-funcional, paradigma-de-programação

O que são e quais as principais diferenças entre Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos?

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Tentei responder da forma mais sucinta que pude, mas também senti que na forma como está ela está muito ampla. Uma forma de melhorá-la seria colocar parâmetros que guiem as respostas (em vez de deixar segundo a interpretação de cada um). Pois se várias boas respostas surgirem - cada uma abordando a pergunta por um ângulo diferente - como você vai escolher uma como "certa"? E isso - a *possibilidade* que seja de se aceitar uma resposta - é o que diferencia uma "pergunta" de uma discussão aberta (o que, mesmo que frutífera, não se adequa ao formato do site).

Comment: Concordo com o @mgibsonbr (e a resposta dele me ganhou na primeira frase). O que te interessa mais na pergunta, programação funcional ou orientação a (ok, *por*) objetos? Não são dois conceitos diretamente comparáveis.

Comment: @mgibsonbr não sei se o problema aqui seria ter várias respostas certas e não saber qual escolher! Por exemplo, uma questão bem simples e direta como esta ( http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7527/como-consolidar-agregar-ou-agrupar-os-valores-em-uma-base-de-dados) teve 4 respostas corretas e escolher uma delas foi arbitrário, pois nenhuma é intrinsecamente melhor! Concordo que a pergunta está um pouco aberta, mas penso que, apesar de a pergunta pode ser vista ângulos diferentes, existe um noção de completude para julgar uma resposta como mais completa e as outras como complementares!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Na teoria, comparar esses dois paradigmas não faz sentido: a **programação funcional**, a **programação imperativa** e a **programação em lógica** (dentre outras) referem-se à maneira como uma determinada computação é descrita - respectivamente, em forma de funções matemáticas ([cálculo lambda](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_lambda)), em forma de instruções explícitas para a máquina ([arquitetura de Von Neumann](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_de_von_Neumann)), e em forma de predicados lógicos a serem provados por indução ([resolução](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_resolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o) em [lógica de primeira ordem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_de_primeira_ordem) com [retrocesso](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)). Já a **programação orientada por objetos** tem mais a ver com a forma que as estruturas de dados de um programa são combinadas/unidas com as subrotinas que lidram com essas estruturas (i.e. junta-se os dados e o comportamento numa mesma estrutura lógica).

Ou seja, pode-se ter uma linguagem que é ao mesmo tempo funcional e orientada por objetos - da mesma forma que pode-se ter uma que não segue nenhum dos dois paradigmas.

Na prática, a maioria das linguagens orientadas por objeto seguem o paradigma imperativo, e da mesma forma muitas linguagens funcionais (como Lisp) incluem características não funcionais - como variáveis de estado. Por essa razão, no restante da resposta vou considerar a orientação por objetos num contexto imperativo - ainda que em princípio seja possível aplicá-lo a outros contextos.

### Programação Funcional

A programação funcional baseia-se no conceito matemático de [função](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28matem%C3%A1tica%29), em que para cada elemento do seu conjunto domínio (entrada) há apenas um elemento no seu conjunto contra-domínio (saída). Além disso, as funções são normalmente expressas por meio de outras funções - de modo que obter o valor da função para um determinado conjunto de parâmetros envolve não só aplicar as regras daquela função, mas também fazer uso de outras funções.

Por essa razão, a programação funcional não possui o conceito de "variáveis de estado"; se um valor qualquer (seja ele numérico, textual, um vetor, matriz, ou algo mais complexo) aparece num momento qualquer da computação, considera-se que aquele valor é único e imutável durante todo o processo. Pode-se estabelecer **relações** entre valores - como dizer que `2` é a metade de `4` - mas o valor `2` sempre será um `2` e o `4` sempre será um `4`.

### Programação Orientada por Objetos

Na programação imperativa considera-se que as estruturas de dados (de novo, números, texto, vetores, matrizes, etc) existem em um determinado **estado**, e que através de comandos específicos para o computador esse estado vai sendo alterado no decorrer do programa, de modo que ao final da execução ele represente as consequências de um processo lógico. Os comandos disponíveis são fixos pela linguagem, e normalmente há comandos distintos para tratar de [tipos de dados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_dado) distintos.

O conceito de "objeto" é uma extensão desse comportamento para além dos tipos de dados da própria linguagem, aplicando-os também aos tipos definidos pelo usuário: para cada estrutura de dados definida, define-se também uma série de operações que podem ser aplicadas a esse estrutura - em geral influenciadas pelo seu estado interno - e a partir de então permite-se usar essas estruturas como tipos distintos, e não como estruturas de dados genéricas. Some-se a isso o conceito de "tipos mais genéricos" e "tipos mais específicos" (i.e. herança), e temos a possibilidade de criar uma taxonomia rica de tipos cada um com suas operações - de modo que os programas possam ser expressos num **nível de abstração mais alto** do que aqueles que utilizem somente os tipos fornecidos pela linguagem de programação em si.

Quando os objetos e suas relações são o ponto central de uma linguagem de proramação, diz-se que ela é "orientada por objetos" (ou, no popular, orientada *a* objetos) - pois todo o fluxo lógico do programa se baseia em quais objetos existem e como eles interagem entre si. Ou seja, inicialmente esses objetos estão lá - em seu estado inicial - e à medida que o programa interage com o seu ambiente (seja atraves de uma entrada, ou através da interação com o usuário) esse objetos vão mudando de estado.

### Semelhanças

- Da mesma forma que uma função possui domínio e contra-domínio, um objeto possui operações que somente são aplicáveis a ele em particular.
- Assim como um conjunto pode possuir subconjuntos, um objeto pode ter subtipos; e tal como um elemento do subconjunto pode ser usado como parâmetro para uma função que tem o conjunto principal como domínio, um objeto do subtipo herda todas as operações do seu tipo base (i.e. elas se aplicam igualmente e ele).
- Não ha [necessariamente] um ponto de entrada nem de saída num programa funcional: a princípio, qualquer uma de suas funções poderia ser chamada a partir de uma entrada interativa, por exemplo. Da mesma forma, um sistema orientado por objetos não estabelece um "início" nem um "fim" para o programa: cada "mensagem" enviada para um objeto causará uma série de efeitos (e talvez uma resposta), mas não há ordem predefinida para que mensagens serão enviadas.

### Diferenças

- A principal diferença é a questão do estado: uma função por definição não possui **efeitos colaterais**, ela apenas retorna um resultado a partir de um determinado conjunto de parâmetros. Consequentemente, duas ou mais chamadas da mesma função passando os mesmos parâmetros devem produzir resultados iguais - enquanto na POO o resultado pode variar conforme o estado do objeto no momento em que a mensagen foi enviada.
- Como consequência disso, enquanto na POO um objeto pode ser ignorante em relação aos demais objetos que compõem o sistema (bastando ele conhecer seus vizinhos mais próximos e enviar mensagens a eles) - reduzindo o acoplamento - isso é mais difícil de ser atingido na programação funcional (e pela minha experiência, também na lógica) por conta da imutabilidade das estruturas de dados.

  - Exemplificando, se a entidade `A` possui uma referência para a entidade `B`, e o estado interno de `B` muda, não é preciso notificar `A` pois as mensagens subsequentes que elas trocarem serão influenciadas pela mudança de estado (em POO). Já no paradigma funcional, `A` e `B` são resultados de uma computação - válida agora e pra todo o sempre; se uma outra computação produziu um `B'`, então é necessário se produzir também um `A'` de modo que a relação desejada entre o `B` "novo" e o `A` se adeque à sua nova configuração.
- Por outro lado, essa independência em relação a um estado torna bem mais simples avaliar e depurar programas funcionais - pois eles podem ser testados parte-a-parte e o resultado do todo será idêntico à soma das partes. Enquanto que no POO às vezes é difícil reproduzir - ou mesmo descobrir - o estado em que um conjunto de objetos estava quando um comportamento inesperado ocorreu, de modo a inspecionar seu comportamento.

Comment: O conceito de função em programação funcional é **diferente** do que é usado no resto da matemática. Linguagens funcionais em geral contém [funções parciais](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_parcial): para um dado `X`, ou `f(X)` é um valor do contra-domínio ou a função não retorna (devido a um loop infinito, exceção, etc), o que não acontece com funções da teoria dos conjuntos.

Comment: @darque Imagino que você se refere ao fato dessas linguagens não verificarem se o parâmetro pertence estritamente ao domínio da função, certo? Ex.: em `f(x) = 1/x` o domínio é `ℕ*`, não `ℕ`; mas se a função foi definida para receber um `int`, ela poderia a princípio receber um `0` (causando uma exceção).

Answer (score 44):

A resposta do mgibsonbr é excelente e eu não poderia ter feito melhor. Vou apenas colocar algo um pouco diferente:

| Funcional | OOP |
| --- | --- |
| Baseada em funções matemáticas | Baseada em formas e comportamentos de objetos através de campos e métodos |
| Lambda Calculus | Baseada em formas e comportamentos de objetos através de campos e métodos |
| Princípio da Composicionalidade | Herança e Abstração |
| Recursão | Polimorfismo |
| Transparência referencial | Encapsulamento |
| Pureza computacional (sem efeitos colaterais) | Efeitos colaterais |
| Lazy evaluation (execução atrasada) | Eager evaluation (execução imediata) |
| Imutabilidade | Dados são mutáveis |
| Linhagem baseada em "macros" (Lisp) ou "pattern matching" (ML) | Linhagem baseada em "classes" (C++) ou "protótipos" (Javascript) |
| Coisas definidas com muitos comportamentos | Muitas coisas e comportamentos definidos |
| Fórmulas/ações em primeiro lugar | Dados/substantivos em primeiro lugar |
| Procura a correção do código | Procura o reuso de código |
| Ordem de execução não importa (paralelismo) | Ordem de execução é importante |
| Dados vagamente acoplados a funções | Dados e funções fortemente acoplados |
| Concisão (opinião?) | Explicitude (opinião?) |
| Lisp, Scheme, ML, Scala, F#, Haskell, Erlang | Smalltalk, C++, Java, Python, Ruby, JS |

Claro que aí estão alguns pontos que ajudam entender as diferenças entre elas. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre cada ponto, daria um livro. O assunto é um pouco mais complexo que isso e há algumas imprecisões para simplificar a exposição. A tabela não deve ser interpretada como um comparativo definitivo das diferenças. Nem tão pouco que seja um "ou você escolhe um ou outro aspecto de cada lado da tabela".

Um dos pontos mais importantes é que linguagens puras em um [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) costumam ser menos úteis na maioria das aplicações do mundo real e não alcançam grande sucesso. Por razões técnicas ou por cultura, linguagens mais próximas do paradigma imperativo são mais populares.

Na verdade em OOP, as únicas **linguagens populares são essencialmente imperativas com características de orientação a objetos e implementam vários conceitos de programação funcional**. E o principal conceito do paradigma, que é a herança, é frequentemente desencorajado. Algumas pessoas colocam outro conceito como principal, mas outros conceitos sequer são exclusivos da orientação a objeto.

Linguagens funcionais que não permitem nenhum tipo de mudança de estado, ou efeitos colaterais (mesmo que controlados) têm [utilidade extremamente prejudicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257582/101) para a maioria dos problemas.

Não se deixe enganar quando tentam vender pureza de paradigma. Isso é ótimo na academia. Nenhum paradigma é panaceia para qualquer coisa.

Ambos paradigmas fornecem abstrações, portanto ineficiências estarão presentes, cada um com sua característica. Para reduzir as ineficiências a pureza de paradigma deve ser deixada de lado; e quanto mais se aproximam do imperativo, mais próximos estão do processamento concreto.

Complementando de acordo com os comentários abaixo, os conceitos são ortogonais, e se não ficou claro, em linguagens do "mundo real" ou elas são funcionais ou são imperativas com características orientadas a objeto.

[image: OOP de Alan Kay X Bjarne Stroustrup]

[Orientação a objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) é tema tão complicado que ninguém tem uma definição clara do que seja. Para cada pessoa que você perguntar ela vai dar sua definição. Então se alguém disser que você está errado, provavelmente você está mesmo, mas não da forma que a pessoa está dizendo :) E o Alan Kay, criador do termo, admite mais recentemente que Smalltalk, sua linguagem, é na verdade orientada à mensagens e não objetos ([veja outra polêmica](https://medium.com/@devraiz/a-pol%C3%AAmica-da-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objeto-fd3bc23deee)).

E é triste que muitas pessoas acham que estão programando orientado a objeto e não estão, é como escrever um livro tendo tomando pau nas aulas de comunicação e expressão. Chegam ao ponto de se discutir qual linguagem é mais orientada a objeto que a outra, Java ou C# (entre outras). Ambas são bem pouco orientadas a objeto (aaahhhh, o marketing), e recomenda-se usar pouco as características desse paradigma. Isto ocorre porque cada um acha que determinada característica é mais importante que outra e nenhuma implementa todas as características do paradigma puramente. Ainda bem!

E linguagens funcionais estão longe da polêmica? Não, muitas pessoas consideram que Lisp, que foi a primeira linguagem funcional, não é puramente funcional e só as baseadas em ML é que são. E mais, há quem diga que Lisp é uma das linguagens mais orientadas a objeto que existem (o próprio criador do termo).

Alguns dizem que orientação sequer é paradigma, e este é só mais um motivo para mostrar que eles são ortogonais.

Hoje as linguagens novas e as que estão querendo estar atualizadas aderem cada vez mais ao paradigma funcional. Claro, não puramente, apenas de forma pragmática. Coloquei na tabela Scala e F# no funcional porque elas se vendem assim, mas são bem imperativas também, e implementam tudo de importante da orientação a objetos. Então até imperativo e funcional podem ser usados juntos, ainda que aí existe um paradigma que seja forte e o outro só auxiliar. C# é um exemplo de linguagem imperativa que está cada dia mais funcional, mas nunca deixará de ser predominantemente imperativa, e manterá sua orientação a objeto (mas que tem papel cada vez menos importante, desde o 2.0 isso vem caindo).

Na organização do código, em sua estrutura de dados que tem mais a ver com OOP, o imperativo [procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101)/[modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) e até o funcional se mostra mais útil que o orientado a objeto puro. Muitos não percebem isto e seguem fazendo sempre igual seguindo a receita de bolo que aprendeu. As pessoas usam OOP como uma "boa prática" (pesquise aqui o que acho disto). Boa prática é saber o que está fazendo e adotar o que é melhor para cada caso. Composição é o segredo para fazer boa manutenção e hoje quem não desgruda de OOP cria objetos que nada tem a ver com a ideia inicial do paradigma e é comum modularizarem tanto que beira o funcional, modular e até procedural, mas como está dentro de uma classe, acham que não.

[image: Paradigmas]

Expus alguns fatos e dei algumas opiniões, até porque este é um assunto ainda não tão bem definido e entendido por todos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que essa tabela nao faz muito sentido - functional programming e OOP sao conceitos ortogonais, e podem coexistir. Nao faz sentido comparar um versus o outro. Scala, por exemplo, promove functional programming *e* e' 100% orientada a objectos - de tal modo, que substitui metodos/classes estaticos por companion objects. F# tambem e' orientado a objectos. Creio que a comparacao devia ser imperative programming vs functional programming.

Comment: @dcastro Então leia todo o texto, você repetiu o que eu disse em outras palavras. E o que eu não disse, fiz referência a resposta que o mgibsonbr com a qual concordo 100%. Se eu fizesse uma comparação diferente, eu não estaria respondendo o que foi perguntado. Depois eu complemento para deixar mais explícito. Eu entendi o que você disse, não estou questionando, mas se for para ser absolutamente preciso, Scala ou F# não são 100% OOP, elas podem ser tanto quanto Java, C#, C++ ou outras linguagens OOP populares, e nenhuma é 100% OOP.

Comment: Eu acho que você não está dizendo que que 100% da linguagem OOP, afinal você mesmo disse que essas linguagens também são funcionais (e complemento que são também pelo menos imperativas, há outros paradigmas), mesmo que fosse 1% funcional (e é muito mais) a aritmética já não bateria. Se você diz que ela implementa 100% do conceitos OOP, então, bem, o Alan Kay discorda de você. De qualquer forma você pode argumentar de outra forma se eu não entendi algo. Só gostaria que enfatizar, que entendi o que você disse e concordo com tudo. Apenas estou dizendo que ser 100% preciso não ajuda o entendimento

Comment: Nao sei em relacao a F#, mas Scala e' 100% orientada a objectos, no sentido em que todos os valores sao objectos, e todos as operacoes sao chamadas a metodos de objectos. C# nao e' 100%, porque os metodos/operadores estaticos nao pertecem a nenhum objecto. O mesmo acontece em Java, onde existem tipos primitivos, que tambem nao sao objectos (tanto quanto sei). Eu so' quiz dizer que os dois conceitos nao sao opostos, nao sao preto e branco, por isso achei que uma tabela de comparacao nao faz muito sentido. Eu concordei com o resto do texto, mas acho que este ponto e' central e nao ficou claro.

Comment: Posto de outra forma: E' possivel escrever um programa usando apenas objectos, e escrito completamente num estilo funcional. A tabela de comparacao leva a crer que tenho que optar por um dos dois.

Comment: Em negrito: "linguagens populares são essencialmente imperativas com características de orientação a objetos e implementam vários conceitos de programação funcional.". Além disso, orientada a objetos e **usando** objetos não me parecem sinônimos, então creio que a tabela não tem problema nenhum como forma de distiguir as diferenças perceptíveis nos conceitos.

Comment: @Bacco Exato, a ideia da tabela é tornar os conceitos acessíveis para as pessoas. Ela não é uma tese. Ela pode ter até algumas incorreções e certamente não está completa. Se há informações que podem ajudar melhorá-la, estou ouvindo a todos. E eu falei sobre a simplificação feita, falei que os paradigmas se complementam. Mas vou clarificar ainda mais.

Comment: @Maniero, eu, como a grande maioria dos programadores (imagino), tenho zero de experiência com linguagens funcionais. Então, quando você diz "*C# é um exemplo de linguagem imperativa que está cada dia mais funcional*", que aspectos da linguagem são esses que você diz que são funcionais?

Comment: @PedroGaspar Fica complicado listar tudo isso em comentários.

Answer (score -6):

A orientação a objetos tem por objetivo espelhar o mundo real. Por exemplo: um carro, podemos inserir ele no sistema, o que transformaria ele em objeto.
       Este objeto possui atributos (como cor, marca de fabricante, potência e etc) que o distingue de outros objetos.
É uma disciplina e tipo de programação que gosto e prefiro, mas fiz um resumo pois a matéria é muito extensa.
Espero que minha resposta tenha ajudado(a).