# Por que orientação a objetos não serve para a maioria dos cenários?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software

[Citação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277179/357) de Maniero:

> É o maior problema que temos na nossa área, e vem piorando: algo muito bom é criado e serve para 1% dos problemas, quem sabe 10%, mas as pessoas querem usar para 100% deles.

[Citação](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198675/what-makes-oop-good#comment386081_198675) de SK-logic:

> OOP is pretty useless outside of a very narrow field (namely, agent-based simulations).

Adicionado a isso há o *hype* de OOP, que foi adotada pela indústria de software como bala de prata para inúmeros cenários.

Pode-se dizer que a orientação a objetos serve (traz benefício) para bem poucos problemas.

Para quais cenários/domínios a orientação a objetos serve?

Por que a orientação a objetos não serve para a maioria dos cenários/domínios?

Em quais cenários/domínios ela é mais ou menos neutra?

Comment: Só uma pergunta sobre a sua pergunta: `Fala-se que orientação a objetos serve (traz benefício) para bem poucos cenários/domínios.` quem disse isso, poderia colocar fontes nem que fosse links, videos, etc ... Quem falou, como falou? desculpa está intrometendo, mas, eu todas as vezes que vejo esse tipo de pergunta dizendo "Falam" eu acho legal dizer quem falou, uma referencia sei lá algo do tipo.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277179/357

Comment: Então Piovezan poderia então (se quiser é claro, só uma idéia) colocar quem disse com esse link ligando a esse pensamento ... porque, "Falam" eu acredito ser mais que uma pessoa. Não me leve a mau só gostaria realmente de entender o "Falam"

Comment: Outra coisa eu gostei da pergunta, acho esse assunto interessante.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Orientação a objeto ajuda gerenciar **complexidade**. Onde não tem complexidade ela é uma ferramenta desnecessária.

Curiosamente ela adiciona complexidade, por isso quanto mais faz OOP mais precisa de OOP, é endêmico. Claro, pode ser necessária, pode ser útil. O problema maior é quando você tem complexidade artificial, por modelagem errada, feita sem pensar, sem tempo para planejar e principalmente entender o problema real. O trabalho do desenvolvedor é achar uma solução mais adequada, não é achar qualquer solução.

Complexidade natural existe em projetos grandes, de preferência com muitos programadores envolvidos, ou então em projetos tão grandes que eles saem do controle, por exemplo em *frameworks*, onde o projeto começa com quem o desenvolveu mas só termina com que o consome, acho que dá para imaginar como é complexo gerenciar essa passagem.

Tudo o que o Alexei disse é verdade em uma resposta surpreendentemente boa para usuários que a gente conhece pouco por aqui (ele precisa participar mais :) ), ainda que não sei se respondeu :). OOP funciona melhor quando há equipes diferentes trabalhando no projeto e entenda o projeto como a solução inteira, todas as partes que são combinadas, até aquelas que vem junto com a linguagem.

Fazer o projeto OO obriga você pensar no que está criando de forma mais ampla, com mais detalhes, considerando mais as interações, entender o cenário. Sem esse entendimento não dá certo. Um dos motivos que a maioria dos códigos (pseudo) "orientados a objeto" que vemos por aí serem ruins é porque as pessoas não entendem que a ferramenta foi bolada para induzir você entender melhor o problema com visão global. Não sabendo disso a pessoa está desperdiçando seu tempo com mecanismos que adicionaram complexidade e não trouxeram benefícios. OOP não garante nada melhor, tem que saber fazer, sempre, em qualquer coisa.

E dá para gerenciar bem essa complexidade toda sem OOP, só não é tão comum usar outras porque essa foi a ferramenta mais ensinada.

## Reuso

Alguns dizem hoje em dia que OO não é sobre o reuso, mas sempre foi. E de fato ela ajuda você fazer coisas mais reusáveis, mais intercambiáveis, facilita compor melhor, estender funcionalidade, isolar certas partes, e principalmente tornar as características do objeto mais facilmente descobríveis. Então em cenários de reuso OO ajuda muito. É o caso de GUI. Aplicações que tem muitas partes baseadas em outras partes e que em cada situação precisa ter uma forma um pouco diferente.

## Caixa preta

OOP cria uma caixa preta, sabe, é como você for criar um motor e cada parte dele é projetado por uma equipe [de forma completa e essa parte só tem uma comunicação básica com outras partes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Internamente outras equipes não precisam saber o que acontece ali (mas deveria entender bem como usa, as consequências de fazer qualquer coisa, e isto não costuma acontecer na prática, o que é triste). Isso isola a complexidade.

## Muitos estados e comportamentos e relacionamentos diretos

Quanto mais complexos devem ser os objetos (muitos estados, muitos comportamentos) mais OOP faz sentido. Se os objetos ficam simples demais faz pouco ou nenhuma diferença programar de outra forma, principalmente se esta outra forma ainda for modular, que é uma característica importante. Mas a indústria se apegou à modularização via objetos. Só não ache que estou dizendo que OOP é objeto grande sempre. Tem também um pouco a ver como tudo isso se relaciona.

Vira e mexe aparece um aqui que cria um objeto complexo, todo modular, com responsabilidades únicas, tudo direitinho, aí ele fala que precisa garantir que os métodos sejam executados em ordem específica. Pronto a pessoa não entendeu para que serve a ferramenta e usou só porque está na moda.

## Exemplos

Um **jogo** costuma ter uma quantidade enorme de objetos com ações diversas concomitantes, tendo relações entre eles, e podem ter objetos novos se relacionando com os existentes, muitas instâncias. Parece um bom cenário, não? Para certas partes.

Um **ERP de plataforma** que serão personalizados por clientes deveriam ser OO, não acha? Um ERP de plataforma é um ***framework***. Um ERP interno nem tanto. Isso parece um erro. A não ser que mesmo internamente esteja criando praticamente uma plataforma. Mas será que é o certo? Será que vale o esforço manter algo tão organizado, e isto tem custo adicional para algo que pode ser mais facilmente manipulado pela equipe interna? Há casos que sim e casos que não. Poucos casos você tem domínios de negócios que se encaixam tão bem com objetos nesse sentido. Os objetos mudam demais, pra manter flexível é preciso separar tudo em partes muitos granulares, ao ponto que praticamente você não tem mais objetos úteis, tem uma amontoado de classes que nem são objetos reais, no máximo está criando abstrações, e OOP não é só abstração, e abstração você consegue de outras formas.

#### <strike>Regras de negócio</strike>

Regras de negócios são voláteis demais para tentar montar objetos como se faz em GUI, por exemplo. Há evolução em elementos genéricos de tela do seu desktop ou mobile, mas essas mudanças são sempre em detalhes pequenos, mais controlados. Em uma aplicação LOB pode haver mudanças radicais, mesmo que as mais radicais não sejam tão frequentes. Nesses cenários a mudança é tão grande que OOP acaba não fazendo diferença. Para ajudar esses cenários depois de constatado que OOP sozinho não ajudava criaram outras coisas como o DDD por exemplo. A quantidade de complexidade que ele adiciona é tão grande que raríssimos cenários são úteis. Tenho visto casos de pessoas que o adotaram porque estava na moda e houve enorme arrependimento, ou nem perceberam ainda o quanto se tornaram improdutivos.

Mas claro, você pode criar um boleto abstrato e depois derivar em boletos específicos de bancos. Faz todo sentido. Só note que isso é mais um **mecanismo** do que uma regra de negócio. OOP se dá melhor com mecanismos. Não quer dizer que não pode usar em regra de negócio, mas ao contrário do que muita gente diz (em geral pessoas que não passam anos dando manutenção no mesmo software pra falar se tudo o que ela fez sobreviveu ao tempo) OOP complica a manutenção, engessa certas coisas. Reestruturar um objeto fechado é mais complicado que partes mais soltas. A solução que muitas vezes OOP dá é criar versões novas desse objeto estendendo o original. No longo prazo isso é terrível, não escala e vai gerando confusão, pra usar essa vantagem de OOP começa ter maluquices como `Cliente2`, `ClienteNovo`, `Cliente2019`. Raro fazerem isso, mas normalmente a solução não é orientada a objeto, simplesmente a pessoa refaz o objeto e vai consertando no sistema para se adaptar à nova versão.

Domínios onde você tem amplo conhecimento e que não mudarão tanto funciona melhor. Para tornar OOP mais fácil de mexer e refatorar, criam objetos tão pequenos que praticamente deixa de ser OOP, mas como ainda usa classes a pessoa acha que é OOP.

Não se esqueça que OOP foi essencialmente criada para **GUI**. Depois acharam que poderiam usar em outras coisas. Algumas acertaram, outras não. Todas, se feitas corretamente, podem dar certo, mas pode não ser a melhor solução, ou pode não trazer benefícios reais. Não há estudos que indicam que OOP traz os benefícios que vendem, cada um tem sua percepção. Passei a minha. Em GUI eu vejo fácil que tem benefício. Em vários **mecanismos** também. GUI é mecanismo.

## Contra exemplos

Por isso acho estranho OOP em PHP que é composto por *scripts*, ou o seu uso em microsserviços que existem para quebrar grandes problemas em minúsculos problemas que se comunicam por protocolos externos que nada tem a ver com código.

Quer uma prova que sistemas complexos, onde muita gente trabalha no projeto, podem ser feitos sem OOP? Sistemas operacionais. Tome o Linux, já deve estar perto das 100 milhões de linhas, muitos milhares de programadores trabalhando, não pode sair nada errado, tem que evoluir bem, e evolui muito. Claro, sempre são bons programadores que mexem ali. E isso é mais importante.

## OOP é sobre [mediocridade](https://dicionario.priberam.org/med%C3%ADocre)

É paradoxal, mas em geral cenários com programadores ruins tendem a usar mais OOP. Em alguns casos de forma consciente. É mais fácil uma pessoa arquitetar a solução em termos de classes e suas relações e deixar programadores inferiores implementarem os códigos. Mas em muitos casos isso ocorre por acidente. Aí não tem solução, qualquer ferramenta produzirá uma aplicação ruim.

É mais fácil gerenciar problemas de programadores ruins quando você tem objetos mais definidos, que não precisa ter certas preocupações que outras soluções exigem.

Equipes que giram muito podem se beneficiar por ter esses objetos mais caixa preta. Mas para esses cenários é possível ter boas soluções fora de OOP.

## Adendo

Já que ninguém pergunta vou aproveitar para fazer de Agile X Waterfall que é sobre complexidade de projetos.

Waterfall foi criado nos anos 60, ainda que não formalizado. Os projetos naquela época eram muito pequenos, não passavam de alguns poucos KB. Nos anos 70 a sua adoção mais formal ocorreu dentro da IBM e empresas que a reproduziam a cultura. Ela documentava muito e servia de base para grande parte da "inovação" do TI, naquela época ainda chamado de PD. O erro é que os projetos ficaram grandes e eles continuaram assim. Desenvolvedores independentes não tinham acesso a esse material e usavam o Waterfall em iterações curtas, tudo de forma natural, intuitiva. Isso se deu muito nos anos 80. Nos anos 90 pegou moda o tal do Agile que foi uma rebelião contra o Waterfall. Agile nada mais é que Waterfall quebrando em partes.

Só que quase todo mundo já fazia isso. E dá certo quando a pessoa sabe como fazer. Quando não sabe, qualquer coisa dá errado. O que aconteceu foi uma enorme venda de livros, cursos, consultorias para ensinar as pessoas fazerem o que elas já faziam. A criação do Agile em si é contra tudo isso que falam de Agile. [Ele tem literalmente 4 linhas](https://agilemanifesto.org/), o resto é invenção para indústria ganhar dinheiro. **Advocacia de Agile é vender geladeira pra esquimó**.

Por isso eu digo que as pessoas deveriam se preocupar mais em fazer softwares organizados do que fazer OOP. **Orientação a objeto é só um meio, não o fim**.

## Conclusão

Programar orientado a objeto é bem diferente de consumir coisas criadas com orientação a objeto.

Sua adoção exagerada tem a ver com o tal do [efeito Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) e em específico o [viés cognitivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "OOP cria uma caixa preta": uma das maiores verdades e maiores utilidades. Pretendia dar uma colaborada com essa pergunta, mas antes preciso ler sua resposta para ver se tenho algo a acrescer, ou se fico mesmo nas experiências profissionais programando mais OOP em determinados projetos e totalmente anêmico/procedural em outros projetos da mesma empresa

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se tiver mais que uma vírgula pra acrescentar manda ver, sempre é bom ter uma visão diferente ou complementar. Eu preciso retomá-la

Answer (score 6):

As vantagens da orientação a objetos aparecem apenas em projetos grandes.

Dá muito trabalho desmembrar um problema em pequenas peças orientadas a objetos, porque a orquestração dessas peças é muitas vezes maior do que a sua criação.

Ficam brincando que a coisa mais chata de Java por exemplo é criar uma Factory. Criar um objeto com x características é relativamente fácil. Difícil é criar uma "mãe" que seria a tal fábrica, que deve saber exatamente como cada filho deve ser criado, e que deve saber interagir com outros para trazê-lo a vida.

Ora, vc deve estar se perguntando, se é tão difícil assim criar peças orientadas a objetos, porque raios ainda é mais útil fazer isso em projetos grandes? Simples,

Em projetos grandes, temos várias pessoas envolvidas, e várias equipes envolvidas. Se cada um faz um objeto relativamente pequeno, comparado ao todo do projeto - e estamos falando aqui também das chatas Factories - com um escopo bem definido, você leva menos tempo para terminar o projeto.

É muito mais difícil fazer isso em um projeto que não usa a OO, porque cada passo de uma lógica depende do outro. Em OO não importa como vc faz uma coisa, importa apenas o que aquilo lhe provê, e o que aquilo precisa.

E mais ainda: se vc precisa de um objeto que já foi feito em outro projeto, o que vc faz em OO? Simples, vc usa o objeto, muito mais fácil e menos propenso a erros do que copiar-e-colar código.

Answer (score 1):

#### Uso da orientação a objetos

Realmente, a orientação a objetos não serve para todos os cenários. Dependendo do tamanho do projeto, desmembrar o problemas em vários objetos gera mais complexidade do que o próprio problema em si.

Vejo que a orientação a objetos é colocada no pedestal e a procedural é vista como algo "defasado". Isso não faz sentido, pois são visões diferentes para fazer determinada ação. Acho importante ter consciência de que nada é unânime, muito menos paradigmas de programação.

Entre os cenários onde o paradigma não é vantajoso estão:

- Projetos bem pequenos.
- Scripts pequenos para automação de alguma tarefa.

Answer (score 1):

## Orientação a objetos é uma estratégia

Orientação a objetos é uma estratégia para auxiliar o processo de *design*. O SWEBOK, versão 3 ([aqui](https://www.computer.org/education/bodies-of-knowledge/software-engineering)), registra o "corpo de conhecimento" da engenharia de software e fornece detalhes.

Assim como outras estratégias, não foi desenvolvida nem indicada para "todos" os cenários. Dito isto, talvez seja interessante observar o que cada estratégia oferece de "bom" e em qual cenário empregá-la. Neste sentido, há uma questão no próprio Stackoverflow que pode ajudar, ao esclarecer as diferenças e usos entre programação orientada a objetos e aquela dita funcional ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13372/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funcional-e-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos-o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-quais-suas)).

Comment: O nosso site parece ter respostas bem melhores que do SOen https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101 Legal ter citado o SWEBOK, só achei que poderia ter caprichando um pouco mais na resposta como um todo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo questão em português, fiz a atualização.