# Python - Dúvida relacionada a estrutura, acredito eu

Tags: python-3.x

Alguém pode me explicar o que é e em que situação se aplica o modo de criar métodos abaixo:

```
 def show_preprar_dados(self) -> object:
        pass
```

Não sei o que quer dizer e para que serve quando aparece a setinha ao lado no nome da função.

Não sei se abri a pergunta corretamente para esse assunto, me ajudem.

Grato pela compreensão.

Comment: Tu  conhece como funciona as tipagens em outras linguagens? Alguma vez ja declarou uma variavel do tipo objeto em outra linguagem?

Comment: Tipagem que eu conheço, até por que sou novo ainda, é quando se declara uma variável do tipo (string, Booleano, Inteiro...) agora não lembro de alguma vez eu ter declarado variável do tipo objeto.
Pode me ajudar a entender como funciona isso e quando posso aplicar isso, e seus benefícios?
Grato.

Comment: Tipos booleanos, inteiros, char, string e float são praticamentes básicas tipagens em linguagens de programação. Já o tipo objeto está presente em linguagens orientadas a objetos como Java, Python, C++ (não é o C comum), PHP, entre outras conhecidas. Variaveis do tipo objeto é como tu inserir um objeto inteiro dentro de uma variável.

Comment: Imagine que tu criou o objeto Animal (que possui a classe animal), e nele possui o método chamado latir(). Vamos supor em uma linguagem qualque. Eu declaro a variavel anim do tipo objeto. Que fica: Animal anim; E a partir dai eu posso exercer o metodo anim.latir().

Comment: Logico que só um exemplo pra tu não se confundir. Mas para isso tu consegue encontra mais respostar nas documentações das linguagens de programação. Que no teu caso é o python. Ir procurando e tentando descobrir como chama um objeto e coloca em uma variavel.

Comment: Então, o objeto Animal que você diz seria um arquivo chamado "Animal.py" no meu caso Python, e dentro eu teria a classe "animal" com um método latir().?

Para declarar a variável do tipo obejto, faria assim:
anim = Animal()

Com isso chamando ela no import. Ou entendi errado?
Por que se for isso, eu já faço isso dessa forma.
Só não entendo por que declaro um método assim:
def metodo_animal(self): -> Animal()

Comment: Nesse teu metodo da pergunta, ele obrigatoriamente transforma esse teu metodo em um objeto. (Objetos nao necessariamentes precisam ser classes). E essa maneira do ->Animal() não vai dar certo. e sim def metodo_latir(self) -> object:

Comment: Creio que te confundi utilizando as classes como exemplo. Não sei como tu esta aprendendo sobre orientação a objetos. Mas sobre a tua pergunta, você esta transformando o seu metodo sendo ele obrigatoriamente um objeto, pose ser float, int, double, mas é object.

Comment: Certo, acho que entendi.
Mas, qual seria a aplicação disso na prática?
O que difere de eu fazer o import de uma classe e declarar um método dessa maneira?

Comment: Analise essa pergunta:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344486/por-que-orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos-n%c3%a3o-serve-para-a-maioria-dos-cen%c3%a1rios

Comment: Espero ter ajudado